# python unicode support

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to figure out how to use the unicode support in python;
I would like to convert this string to unicode :
"ABCDE"
-->
"\x00A\x00B\x00C\x00D\x00E"

Any built-in functionnality can do that, or shall i use join() ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's UTF-16BE, not Unicode.

```
>>> 'ABCDE'.decode('ascii').encode('utf-16be')
'\x00A\x00B\x00C\x00D\x00E'
```

Comment: why would you put in the `.decode('ascii')` bit? It's implied by the `.encode('utf-16be')` (`'\xff'.encode('utf-16be')` will fail with an UnicodeDecodeError ascii codec error the same way as `'\xff'.decode('ascii')` will)

Comment: @Chris: To make it explicit to the reader that it has to be decoded *somehow*.

Answer (score 2):

The key to understanding unicode in python is that unicode means UNICODE. A unicode object is an idealized representation to the characters, not actual bytes.

Answer (score 0):

the str object should be firstly converted to unicode object by decode method.
then convert the unicode object to str object using encode method with character-encoding you want.